# Why the Animation Clip in Timeline is disabled gray I can't change animation clip?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: AQnimcation clip]

Marked it with blue ellipse on the right in the inspector. The field of the Animation Clip is disabled gray. It wasn't before.

Comment: The current version of the editor is 2018.2.5f1 and this was the original version.
Then I tried to change the editor to 2018.3.0b12 but since I had problems I'm running the project again on the 2018.2.5f1 version. 

And it worked fine but for some reason suddenly it become to be disabled.

Comment: Here is a link to the project: https://files.fm/u/dnefhgzx

Comment: on the top left corner: disable `Preview` and check if this solves it

Comment: @derHugo Tried it already didn't work. It's strange. For now I'm changing the animations by deleting/adding them on the animation track it self. But it's strange that it's locked. I will keep checking it.